# Jquery: how to get the selection of parent function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need help with my Jquery:

**Here is my code:**

```
// common varialbles
var current_form;
var all_inputs = " :input";

//common functions
function get_current_form(){
    current_form = "#"+$(this).attr("id");
}

$("#change_password_form").submit(function(e){
    get_current_form();
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url:"process.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:$("#change_password_form").serialize()+'&form_name='+$("#change_password_form").attr("id"),
        success: function(data){
            $("#msg").html(data);
            $(current_form+all_inputs).val("");
        }
    });
});
```

**I wanted to do the following:** While `"#change_password_form"` is submitted, I wanted to get this ID assigned to the `var current_form` through the `function get_current_form()` within ajax.

My purpose is to use the common functions and variables to reduce typing and increase efficiency.
Could someone please help me to fix the above issue? It would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You are not passing the context of current object to get_current_form()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass current object which is `#change_password_form` to your `get_current_form` function:

```
$("#change_password_form").submit(function(e){
    get_current_form(this);
    // Rest of your code here
});
```

and change your function to:

```
function get_current_form(el){
    current_form = "#"+$(el).attr("id");
}
```

But actually I'm not sure what's your expected result here, since you can get the `id` directly using:

```
$("#change_password_form").submit(function(e){
    current_form = this.id;
    // Rest of your code here
});
```